# Apache Solr Replacing "Prefixes" with Pattern

Tags: solr, lucene

This is the setup.

1. querying from mysql `select NULLIF(id,'') as unID <continue with other things..>`
2. In schema.xml, `<field name='unID' type='unIDType' index... />`
3. Also in schema.xml,

`<fieldType name="unIDType" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^([A-Z]{2})?([0-9]{5})$" group="2"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>`

4. Also in schema.xml

`<copyField source='unID' dest='_text_' />`

========

Results:

from mysql:

```
unID
ID00001
ID00002
ID00003
ID00004
.
.
.
```

The rule is that it will always prefix with `ID` and will always `5 digits`.

The users want to search just `00001` and get the answer for that record.

My `PatternTokenizerFactory` works.

If I search unID:10001, I get the records for ID10001.

But I am having trouble putting it to default search field because just querying `q=10001` does not work. `q=unID:10001` works.

edit 1: I also tried the Pattern Filter Factory. It didn't work either.

I think the problem is the new value "00001" is not at default search field, but "ID00001" is.

I read that the analyzing is done after they are all marked as default search field. May be I read it wrong?

=======

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a copyField instruction, the resulting field (_text_) has its own analyzer chain and does not care what the source field does. You may want to look instead into eDisMax as that allows to search multiple fields, instead of catch-all one.

Comment: I chose your 1st approach and make the _text_ has its own type, and put my analyzer there too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default search field (this is not changed automagically by Solr), you can include a field name to search when you call your query parser.

For the [Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser): `df` (&df=unID)

For [the DisMax and eDisMax Query Parsers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf(QueryFields)Parameter): `qf` (&qf=unID).

The default search field is determined from the setting in `schema.xml`:

```
<defaultSearchField>unID</defaultSearchField>
```

or from a definition in your request handler:

```
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">unID</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: I know about that, but I don't want the front end to have complicated quaries with 'eDisMax'. 
Thanks. :)